# Floor for greenhouse

Tags: greenhouse

I read that having an open (directly to earth) floor may cause problems in a greenhouse. So I was thinking of using a foil/barrier plastic to keep the humidity out. On top of that I was thinking of putting a layer of lime plaster or loam/clay plaster to regulate the humidity and give a walkable surface. Or a combination of the above with straw and cement. The plants will be in pots. Anyone suggestions?

Comment: Will your plants be on tables or directly on the floor of the greenhouse?

Comment: Directly on the floor in clay pots

Comment: location makes a huge difference, areas where the ground temperature goes below zero might even need insulation in the floor.  Where is the greenhouse location?

Comment: It is in switzerland. Floor temperature will go to zero in winter. But dont plan to use it in winter. Except maybe to hybernate some plants that would die outside.

Comment: Many green houses in Switzerland have open floor. Humidity are very local problems, so it is very difficult to generalize. Could you describe better the use of greenhouse (you say not to be used in winter).

Comment: It is a medium size garden greenhouse. With plastic windows. I plan to use it to grow tomatoes, eggplants, chillies, peperoni, cucumbers and to keep some lime and olive trees (maybe also overwinter them there).

Answer (score 3):

I used bricks set on a sand bed. It has worked well for 15 years.  Any water spills just disappear, and I drain few gallons at a time from aquariums. You can "sweep" in sand to fill joints if desired. A greenhouse is naturally relatively humid .

Answer (score 2):

work in greenhouse with mixed media floor.  They have a concrete and rock foundation.  It has drainage lines for ease of water flow due to watering or rain pooling.  Find more issues with moss and or fungus on floors than humidity issues.  Also with weed control.  So it depends on how you want to treat the surrounding plants and surfaces to control potential problems such as insects and other critters.

Answer (score 2):

Greenhouses boost humidity too, so bare dirt is not really a problem but it can make your soil or ground more sticky if ambient moisture precipitates on it. Try simple gravel, lay down some sheets of plastic in the areas of the most foot traffic and lay down some gravel.